# How to add a primary key to a View - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I have a View in an Oracle database. I want to use this view in my ASP.NET MVC project. I know that in order to add that view to EF, that view needs to have a primary key. I don't know how to add a primary key as a new column to that view. None of the columns in the view is unique. How can I add that? Thanks.

Comment: Is the a combination of columns which uniquely identify a row in the view?

Comment: `ROWNUM` or `ROW_NUMBER` should be enough.

Comment: @IvanStoev a small snippet would be great.

Comment: @APC unfortunately, no

Comment: `SELECT ROWNUM AS PK, ...` Just additional column to view select list, and then map it as PK in EF.

Comment: @IvanStoev a more explanatory snippet would be great :D I'm new to Oracle so I couldn't do it myself :)

Comment: @IvanStoev on the web, there is only one example with unions, but my code is with joins.

Comment: Do you use the view as read only or should it be updateble as well?

Comment: If your starting position is that even a full column list combination is not unique **there is no view that can save you**. You'll have to dig in your DB design and find or add proper primary keys there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Ivan's comment, you could build your view like this:

```
SELECT rownum, *
  FROM (your_current_view_query)
```

Comment: This approach provides a unique key, but is not determinnistic, i.e. different queries can assign different "primary keys" to one row. This is **not what is expected from a PRIMARY KEY**.